# How using package WTelegram download many photos?

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Class `TL.Message` has only one Media, but sometimes in Telegram messages were published two or three photos or videos.
I looked example https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_DownloadSavedMedia.cs

and it work well.

I correct download only one last photo in the message using the method
`WTelegram.Client.DownloadFileAsync`

How can i download all medias (photos and videos) in one message using package WTelegram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving a media group (album of photos/documents), it consists of a series of (usually) consecutive messages in a chat (one per media) having the same grouped_id value, so you would need to collect all of these messages from the chat, and look for the media in each.

Please note that unfortunately, there is no way to know how many medias/messages the album is composed of.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any examples?